# How can I reliably keep track of answers when using backtracking?

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I've been trying to use backtracking to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/restore-ip-addresses/) but I am having problems with keeping track of the found answers.

My code:

```
class Solution:
    def restore_ip(self, s):
        self.ans = []
        self.backtrack([], s)
        return self.ans

    def backtrack(self, path, s):
        if s == "" and len(path) == 4:
            #print(self.ans)
            self.ans.append(path)
            #print(self.ans)
            return

        if s == "" or len(path) >= 4:
            return

        for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
            if i > 3:
                break
            if int(s[:i]) > 255:
                break
            if i != 1 and s[0] == 0:
                break

            path.append(s[:i])
            self.backtrack(path, s[i:])
            path.pop()

a = Solution()
print(a.restore_ip("25525511135"))
```

When I tried to run this code it outputted this: `[[], []]`;
But I expected this: `[['255', '255', '11', '135'], ['255', '255', '111', '35']]`;
When I uncommented the two print()'s in the code  it outputted this:

```
[['255', '255', '11', '135']]
[['255', '255', '111', '35'], ['255', '255', '111', '35']]
[[], []]
```

From this I deduct that my logic on the whole is correct but the answers stored in the `ans` variable of the `Solution` class got somehow messed up.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python pass arguments by reference, so `path` that you append to `ans` and `path.pop()` are the objects

you need to copy the path object given to backtrack (`path.copy()`in py3, `path[:]`in py2):

```py
self.backtrack(path.copy(), s[i:])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the status of the solution by the return value.

When the solution is found you return `True` and stop backtracking.

P.S.

You can convert the method to static, as the answer is independent of `Solution` object state, thus enabling to solve multiple problems with different threads.

```
class Solution:
    def restore_ip(self, s):
        self.ans = []
        self.backtrack([], s)
        return self.ans

    def backtrack(self, path, s):
        if s == "" and len(path) == 4:
            self.ans = path
            return True

        if s == "" or len(path) >= 4:
            return False

        for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
            if i > 3:
                break
            if int(s[:i]) > 255:
                break
            if i != 1 and s[0] == 0:
                break

            path.append(s[:i])
            if self.backtrack(path, s[i:]):
                return True
            path.pop()

a = Solution()
# ['255', '255', '11', '135']
print(a.restore_ip("25525511135"))
```